# How do I stop printing "null" in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm writing a program that lets the user input 1-5 names and the persons' social security number. The input is taken graphically, and printed in the console. The output should be all the names and soial security numbers, and all this is printed AFTER the user has input all the names/numbers. While my code (kinda) works if I enter five names/soc.numbers, it doesn't really work if I only input 1-4 names. For example, if I enter three persons/soc.number, the outputs look like this: [[person1, soc1], [person2, soc2], [person3, soc3], [null, null], [null, null]]

Now I do know what's wrong: it will always print null when there is no value to be found in the arrays. However, I do not know how to fix this. I was thinking of using a 2D arraylist, however I don't think that's possible since the 2D array HAS to be specifically a [5][2] array. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
package whatever;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class 2Darrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] namnAndSoc = new String[5][2];

    for (int i  = 0; i < 5; i++){   

        UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Print");
        String in;
        in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Give name and social security number");
        if(in==null){
            break;
        }
        String[] line =  in.split(",");


        for (int j = 0; j< 2; j++){

            nameAndSoc[i][j] = line[j];
        }

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(nameAndSoc)+"\t");   

}
}
```

Comment: do a validation while adding the elements to the array

Comment: Just print the array with a loop instead of printing everything with `Arrays.deepToString()`. This way you can decide until which element you want to print. And I'd recommend to store the elements in an Object instead of using a 2D-array.

Comment: this code does throw and NPE if you don't enter anything at all

Comment: Replace null reference with another one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say here you need object Person with name and SSN fields. Then you may have list of persons for example. Handling these kind of data with arrays is a definitely not good, especially when you'll have more attributes than just a name and SSN

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.deepToString()` writes converts null to `"null"`, and if you don't want to do that, you'll have to do one of:

1. Modify the contents of the array, to replace null with `""` wherever it occurs.
2. Write your own output routine instead of using `deepToString()`.

The second option is probably what most developers would choose. A routine like `deepToString()` is generally used for debug and log output, not for "real" program output, as it's seldom in a format that an end-user would appreciate.

You can use techniques such as writing your own string conversion methods that handle nulls in the way you want:

```
 String nullToBlank(String s) {
    return s == null ? "" : s;
 }
```

If you're willing to bring in dependencies, things like Apache Commons IO have tons of convenient methods to help with this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I am not sure how to do this with a for loop. I tried doing something like

              `for(int x = 0; x<5; x++){

   System.out.println(nameAndSoc[i][j]);

  }`

but all I'm getting is that i and j is not initialized

Comment: I think you need to learn what "initialized" means -- the compiler is telling you what your problem is.

Comment: So if I initialize i and j at the beginning of the code, like int i=0; and int j=0; , I still get an error that says ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException... I'm not even sure I'm close to doing the correct thing here

Comment: You need to understand what `nameAndSoc[i][j]` means before writing it and expecting it to work. Maybe go back and study previous exercises until you understand them. SO isn't supposed to be coding 101.